# Should the reputation bonus for marking an answer as accepted be raised?

Tags: feature-request

Right now, marking an answer as accepted gives a +15 bonus to the author of the answer and a +2 bonus for the person marking it accepted.

To me marking answers as accepted is an important part of this site because it lets other users see immediately which answer was most relevant to the OP.

However, quite often no answer is marked as accepted even if there are answers that directly answer the question.

Could it be a good idea to raise the +2 bonus to +3 (or maybe as much as +5) to give more incentive to mark an answer as accepted? What would be potential negative side effects of such a raise?

Comment: We want people accepting answers because they're actually the answer to their question, not because they want rep for accepting some post, regardless of how well it answers the question.

Comment: Good point - however, there's rarely a question marked accepted that doesn't actually answer the question, so it doesn't seem to be a problem right now.

Comment: @E.Villiger I reject the premise, and I also reject the conclusion that increasing the incentive to accept *anything* wouldn't increase the amount of people accepting answers that aren't answering the question.

Comment: @E.Villiger how much of a "problem" are un-accepted answers? Any user of this site worth its rep will tell you the checkmark is nothing. Upvotes are the real indicator of what's good....

Comment: "accepted answers are a fine social contract, but not a good data point for question or answer quality" ([Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/165773))

Comment: The acceptance mark was a bad idea from the start and is the most useless metric we have for determining usefulness.

Comment: @TinyGiant I think this mark is important to teach inexperienced users about Q&A specifics of this site. Without it meta would likely be flooded by questions like, "how is posting here different from other forums" (maybe even more that need-explain-downvotez:). Rep value of accept (slightly but noticeably above that of regular upvote) probably serves the same purpose, emphasize Q&A nature of the site to newcomers who are used to typical forums

Comment: @gnat I disagree

Comment: @TinyGiant wish I could share your disagreement. If only there was a better way to teach newcomers [about Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how: Ask questions, get answers, no distractions..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't mind the change, but I honestly don't think that would make any difference whatsoever.

In my experience it is mostly new users who simply forget, or don't know how they can, mark an answer as accepted. Same applies for up-voting.

As such, a greater incentive wouldn't matter because most aren't aware that there is one already.

On the flip side, you don't want users to start accepting just *any answer* because the incentive is too rewarding to ignore. As stated in the comments, you want users accepting answers that are *actually* helpful.

If anything, the "accept"-feature should be made harder to "miss" because, I agree with you that questions that are obviously answered are often left "unaccepted".

Comment: _"If anything, the "accept"-feature should be made harder to "miss" "_ There could be a note for the OP, just like done with proposed duplicates.

Comment: @Chris we all know you're here for the Meta rep...

Comment: Someone removed my sarcastic "Please accept" comment. lol!